# Problems with arraylist.size being 0 after adding elements

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I have decided to program Monopoly for my half-year project in java. The problem is that i have the streets in a database, all should be pushed into an ArrayList using the constructor, but the .size() method just keeps saying that the size is zero. Let me demonstrate:

```
 static ArrayList<Building> Buildings = new ArrayList<Building>();

//my constructor:
public Building(String color, Object owner, int cost, int rent, int location, String name) {
        this.color = color;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.rent = rent;
        this.location = location;
        this.name = name;
        Buildings.add(this);// this should add the street into the ArrayList Buildings
    }
//and a example of a street:
 Building street1 = new Building("brown", 0, 60, 2, 1, "4th street");
```

through a separate debug.java file i asked the Building class the size of the Buildings ArrayList

```
System.out.println(Building.Buildings.size());
```

and to my surprise it was 0.
Since a lot of my other methods use the size of this arraylist, i need it to not be 0.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: There is not enough information here. It could be that the code that creates buildings is never called. Please create a [mcve]. Note also that according to the Java language conventions, you shouldn't name a variable with an initial Uppercase letter. It should be `buildings`, not `Buildings`.

Comment: It works for me with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area where street1 is defined and initialized may be incorrect (check whether the line of code gets called).
The mentioned code works for me :

```
public class Building {

    static ArrayList<Building> Buildings = new ArrayList<Building>();
    private String color;
    private Object owner;
    private int cost;
    private int rent;
    private int location;
    private String name;

    //my constructor:
    public Building(String color, Object owner, int cost, int rent, int location, String name) {
            this.color = color;
            this.owner = owner;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.rent = rent;
            this.location = location;
            this.name = name;
            Buildings.add(this);// this should add the street into the ArrayList Buildings
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Building street1 = new Building("brown", 0, 60, 2, 1, "4th street");
         System.out.println(Building.Buildings.size());
    }   
}
```

Comment: I had the streets in main before, didn't work, I'll check on pc soon

Answer (score 0):

Okay so,
you need to have the streets in main, AND you need to run the main first.
This has been a stupid question from my side. I thank all that have helped!

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me as well. The others are right. Its possible that when you reach the debug point where the size of the list is 0, the constructor for Building might not have been called yet.

Comment: isn't constructor called when an object(Building) is created??

Comment: that's where the problem was

Comment: You are right, it should be. But its possible that when you are doing this 'separate debug.java file i asked the Building class the size of the Buildings ArrayList', the constructor might not have been called yet.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you caught it.